# Application of Ceva's or Menelaus's Theorems to solve a problem including parallelogram.

Tags: geometry

Consider a parallelogram $ABCD$ and points $P$ and $Q$ laying on $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ respectively. Let $K$ and $L$ be intersection points of triangles $ABQ$ and $CDP$. Prove that line $af(K,L)$ intersects the middle of the parallelogram.

I know I'm supposed to use Ceva's and/or Menelaus's theorems, but I'm completely lost. I think that I need to use diagonals but I can't find a way to associate them with $af(K,L)$. Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $KL \cap DC = H; KL\cap AC = I, KL\cap BD=J$.

Applying Menelaus's theorem to triangle $PDC$  we have

$\dfrac{HC}{HD}.\dfrac{KD}{KP}. \dfrac{PL}{LC}=1$

Applying Menelaus's theorem to triangle $AQC$

$\dfrac{HC}{HQ}.\dfrac{KQ}{KA}.\dfrac{AI}{IC}=1$

Applying Menelaus's theorem to triangle $BDQ$

$\dfrac{HQ}{HD}.\dfrac{DJ}{JB}. \dfrac{BL}{LQ}=1$

We have

$\dfrac{KD}{KP}=\dfrac{KQ}{KA}; \dfrac{LC}{LP}=\dfrac{LQ}{LB}$

Hence

$\dfrac{DJ}{JB}=\dfrac{CI}{IA}\Rightarrow IJ||AB$ or $I\equiv J$

If $I\equiv J$ then $KL$ through the center of the parallelogram.

If $IJ||AB$ then $KL||AB$. So $\dfrac{AK}{KQ}=\dfrac{BL}{LQ}\Rightarrow \dfrac{AP}{DQ}=\dfrac{PB}{QC}\Rightarrow \dfrac{AP}{DQ}=\dfrac{PB}{QC}=\dfrac{AP+PB}{DQ+QC}=1$. Then it is easy to prove that KL passes through the center of the parallelogram

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of Pappus's theorem.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_configuration#:~:text=Pappus's%20hexagon%20theorem%20states%20that,aC%2C%20and%20Z%20%3D%20Bc%20%C2%B7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_configuration#:%7E:text=Pappus%27s%20hexagon%20theorem%20states%20that,aC%2C%20and%20Z%20%3D%20Bc%20%C2%B7).

Comment: Thanks, but my task is to solve the problem using either Ceva's or Menelaus's theorems (maybe i should've made that more clear in the question) and I can't seem to find (at least for now) anything related to Pappu's theorem that would help me with that.